# Switching USB plug between 2 devices

Tags: usb, switches

I wonder if it possible - If I were to use a 8PDT switch, to switch the 8 wires of a USB3 cable between 2 output ports from 1 input, would this be sufficient? Or are there issues I may run in to that I don't understand

Many thanks

Comment: You're issues would be signal integrity. USB needs to be impedance matched to keep the signal good. In theory it could work though, if you can get a switch set up which keeps the impedance match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely it will work, as generic switches are not designed to be used on sensitive multi-gigabit signals. Also it would connect all pins at the same time, while normally USB devices connect power first and then data pins for safe hot-plugging.